# Direct image sheaf of closed injective map.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that we have schemes $X$ and $Y$ and a morphism of schemes $f:X\rightarrow Y$ which is injective and closed (as a map of topological spaces). Consider the direct image sheaf $f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X}$ on $Y$. Then I wonder what we can say about the stalks.

For $y\in Y\backslash f(X)$ we have that $(f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X})_{y} = 0$, which is easy to show.

For $y\in f(X)$, we have $y = f(x)$, and $f^{-1}(y) = x$. Consequently my guess would be that $(f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X})_{y} = \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. In terms of direct limits we have
$(f_{*}\mathcal{O}_{X})_{y} = \lim_{Y\supseteq U\ni y} \mathcal{O}_{X}(f^{-1}(U))$, and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \lim_{X\supseteq V\ni x}\mathcal{O}_{X}(V)$. But I can't talk them equal.

If not, would an additional assumption like every open in $X$ containing $x$ is of the form $f^{-1}(U)$ for some open $U$ in $Y$ make the guess true?

Comment: By closed do you mean topologically closed, or a closed immersion?

Comment: I mean topologically closed, I will make this more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any injective continuous map of topological spaces which is either open or closed is actually a homeomorphism on to its image, so your map $f:X\to Y$ is topologically just the inclusion of a closed subspace. Direct images along such maps preserve stalks, which is an easy exercise: any open set in $X$ is the intersection of some open set in $Y$ with $X$, and $f_*\mathcal{F}$ has the same sections on any two open sets of $Y$ with the same intersection with $X$ by definition, so from this you can construct an isomorphism of the limits.